# Website font not showing up in IE11

Tags: wordpress, internet-explorer, customization, font-face, webfonts

Okay so its time for that ancient problem that keeps coming back. My client's site is looking pretty weird in Internet Explorer. The top menu is out of position simply because its too large and on the rest of the site, it just doesn't seem to show up.

[http:www.imscs.com](http://www.imscs.com)

We're using the custom font 'Open Sans Condensed Light No Subsetting', Wordpress 4.3.1, 'BeTheme' (Theme), and I've tried @font-face with no luck.
Here's the link, if anyone can see what's missing I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: If your client has windows server, it could be that his server is blocking `.woff` files (http://sebduggan.com/blog/serving-web-fonts-from-iis/). Or you'll need to add to his `.htaccess` file `<Files ~ ".(xml|css|jpe?g|png|gif|js|svg|woff|ttf|eot|woff2)$">
Allow from all
</Files>`

Comment: Thanks but that didn't return any results.

Comment: When i view your website in IE11 .. i see a bunch of JS errors in the console. Also in Firefox i see that the fonts are failing `downloadable font: download failed`